# Differential equation - forced oscillations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm unsure on a question which is

A pure tone at 660Hz is produced at $D$ decibels and is aimed at a wine glass. The glass can deforming only to $x\approx 1 $ before breaking. The tone is aimed directly at the glass forcing it at its natural frequency and the vibrations are modelled by the equation $$\ddot{x}+\lambda \dot{x}+\omega^2 x=\frac{10^{(D/10)-8}}{3}\cos (1320\pi t).$$
$\lambda =3.07, \omega =4.15 \times 10^3 $

How loud does the sound have to be so that the glass breaks?

Now I'm not sure if I can assume any initial conditions but I'm not given any explicitly. 
Can anyone help me with this question??

Comment: Yeah it was my question yesterday but the context wasn't clear so I posted the actual question with everything that I have to go by to see what anyone else can make of the problem.

Comment: aahh I kinda just deleted it...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force

Answer (score 1):

$$
\ddot x +λ\dot x+ω^2x=A\cos(ω_0t).
$$
has a particular solution of the form $x(t)=c_0\cos(ω_0t)+c_1\sin(ω_0t)$. Inserting into the equation gives
\begin{align}
(-ω_0^2c_0+ω_0λc_1+ω^2c_0)\cos(ω_0t)+(-ω_0^2c_1-ω_0λc_0+ω^2c_1)\sin(ω_0t)&=A\cos(ω_0t)\\
\end{align}
resulting in
\begin{align}
(ω^2-ω_0^2)c_0+ω_0λc_1&=A\\
-ω_0λc_0+(ω^2-ω_0^2)c_1&=0\\[1em]
c_0&=\frac{(ω^2-ω_0^2)A}{(ω^2-ω_0^2)^2+(ω_0λ)^2}\\
c_1&=\frac{ω_0λA}{(ω^2-ω_0^2)^2+(ω_0λ)^2}\\
\end{align}
At $ω_0\approx ω$, in fact $|ω-ω_0|\ll λ$, the dominant term is $\frac{A}{ω_0λ}\sin(ω_0t)$, so you are looking for $A>ω_0λ$.

The terms with the eigenfrequencies of the left side of the ODE fall like $e^{- λ/2·t}$ and thus are not present for larger times.

Comment: I get a solution which is $$x(t)\approx Ce^{-1.535t} \cos (qt-\phi )+\frac{10^{(D/10)-8}}{38196}\cos\left ( 1320\pi t-\arctan \left (\frac{12731}{25701}\right ) \right ).$$ With a solution in this form how can I find D, when I don't know $t$ nor do I know the value of some of the constants as I wasn't given any initial conditions?